# Python - вопрос по переносу виртуального окружения python с Windows на Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

В Visual Studio Community создан проект python. В рамках проекта создана виртуальная среда средствами VS.

Как правильно переносить проекты на Linux? Нужно ли после копирования проекта на Linux заново создавать в папке проекта виртуальную среду с нужной версией python или созданная в VS среда актуальная и просто ее нужно активировать? Требуется ли инсталлировать пакеты перечисленные в requirement.txt?

Comment: Нужно заново создавать, потому что в окружении устанавливаются библиотеки именно для текущей системы, а не для всех существующих

Comment: Я думаю на счет Docker, но тут тоже не совсем понятно пока. Среда разработки Windows Visual Studio Community. Там я  пишу и отлаживаю код. Далее я должен создать докер файл с OS Linux и там тестировать код. Для этого мне нужно после запуска контейнера нужно будет вызвать pip с requirment.txt  для установки компонентов под линукс.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно будет создать новую виртуальную среду на линукс. Питон и зависимости проекта имеют не только скрипты, но и нативные библиотеки которые не запустятся в не той ОС.

Проверь все ли указанно в Вашем requrements.txt выполнив `pip freeze`. Зависимости зависимостей не важны, но мог что-то пропустить.

Разверни новое окружение, активируй его. Установи зависимости через `pip install - r requirements.txt`. Переходи в папку с проектом и запускайся.

Comment: На практике очень много возьми с установкой окружения и библиотек и нужной версией питона. Хотелось бы более простое решение.

Comment: создай одно окружение на винду и одно для всех убунту.

Comment: cxfreeze, pyinstaller с другой стороны...

Comment: хотя если правильно и полностью оформить пакет с вашим кодом и пип будет собирать нужное окружение сам.

Comment: @eri9 а можно пример правильно оформленого пакета на примере hello world в log файл?

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject вот сам хелловорд